# precedence constraint editor in ssis package

Tags: ssis, editor, package, constraints, operator-precedence

I want to have one SSIS package , in this case I have two varables : x=1 and y=0 and 3 tasks : one is Execute SQL Task (task A) and two Script Task (task B and C) . I want when we select x=1 in task A , task B is run and when select y=0 in task A , task C is run . In precedence constraint editor between A and B I select Expression and Constraint with success value and in precedence constraint editor between A and C I select Expression and Constraint with failure value but I don't know what expression must write in these precedence constraint editor . please help me 
with respect

Answer (score 4):

You will need to set up two Package Variables at design time to hold x and y.

In the General Tab of the Execute SQL component, change the result to SingleRow and ensure the query returns 1 row with the parameter details you require.  Go to the Result Set Tab and set the two Package Variable (x, y) to the columns returned from your query.

Add two workflows, both from Execute SQL component, both On Success.  For the first workflow (going to Task B), set the expression to @[User::x] == 1.  For the second workflow (to Task C), set the expression to @[User::y] == 0.

If you want the options to be mutually exclusive, you are going to have to include two clauses on each workflow (i.e. @[User::x] == 1 && @[User::y] !=0).  You will have to work out all permutations and include them in the expression to avoid both workflows firing.

Comment: In Execute SQl Task Editor in part SQLStatement should I write this query: Declare @x int - Declare @y int - Set @x=1 - Set @y=0 - Select @x or Select @y

Comment: when I write an above query in  Execute SQl Task Editor in part SQLStatement(Declare @x int - Declare @y int -Set @x=1 - Set @y=0 - Select @x) and set the expression to @[User::x] == 1  (going to Task B) with SUCCESS value and set the expression to @[User::y] == 0 (to Task C) with FAILUR value, both task A and task B work good and become green but when I change the query to this : Select @y , task C don't work and again task A and task B work and become green. I want in each time when I change the query only on of the task B or C be run . please help me , with respect

Comment: another question that I have is this : Is it necessary to define x and y as variables before doing enything ???

Comment: It sounds like you are creating local variable (declare...) and not package variables.  Local variables only exist for the lifespan of that component.  You need to use package variables if you want to rely on the values later in the workflow.  Also, forget about failure workflow.  This is for failure of the component, NOT, workflow expression value.  I will add some more detail to the answer to help

Comment: hi Mr.Daryl Wenman and thanks so much for your useful tips , but my problem is still not resolved . I set ResultSet to Single row and set my Connection and write my SQLStatement this way : SELECT x FROM test (I have a table in SQL Server2008 named test , with 2 rows : x int with value 1 and y int with value 0)

Comment: and in Result Set I set : 1 User::x and 0 User::y .I also set 2 variabls : x and y with int data type and with 1 and 0 values . for the first workflow (going to Task B), set the expression to ( @[User::x] == 1 && @[User::y] !=0). For the second workflow (to Task C), set the expression to ( @[User::x] != 1 && @[User::y] == 0) . but in the begining my Execute SQL Task dont work properly and becom red . I dont know why .I want to use my database table and with this relationship write SQL Statement . can you please help me ? with respect

Comment: If your SQL Command is failing, look in the Progress tab (when running in visual studio) as it will tell you what the error is.

Comment: I can't communication between my Execute SQL Task and my database's table with SQLStatement which I write in my sql task.I set ResultSet to NONE and write this query in sql statement:      declare @x int                                                 SELECT x                                                        FROM sales.dbo.t1                                               WHERE x=@x

Comment: and set 2 variabls : x and y with int data type and with 1 and 0 values and I set Parameter Mapping in this way : x / input / long / @x / -1   and   y / input / long / @y / -1

Comment: but every time I run my package , it reads only the value of my variables which I set them and doesn't work with my database . what can I do in order that my package works with my database ?

Comment: You need to set your resultset to single row otherwise you are telling ssis to expect no rows returned.  Change your query so that x and y are on a single row made of column x and column y.  You can then map those columns to your output.  If you are still struggling with the Execute SQL task / setting variables after these tips, I suggest you post a separate question as this is no longer related to your questions' title

Comment: when I set result set to single row, execute sql task works with error and become red .

Comment: should I set parameter mapping or set result set ?

Comment: [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "x": "Single Row result set is specified, but no rows were returned.".
this is a that I catch wen I set result  set to single row

Comment: [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "x": "Single Row result set is specified, but no rows were returned.". this is an error that I catch when I set result set to single row

Comment: can you please tell me how should I write the query ?

Comment: this question that I asked today is the same one that I asked few daya ago . I've not yet solved the problem .

Comment: The question you originally asked was "precedence constraint editor in ssis package" - this is the question answered.  We are now onto "How to write an SQL statement" or "How to use Execute SQL Task to return a single row".  Neither of which relate to "precedence constraints"!  Look back at my previous comments.  First you need get your sql correct and format as two columns, x & y.  Try using this within your exectue sql to get you going "select 1 as x, 2 as y" (without speech marks)